# iPhone application to edit text files

Tags: iphone, software-recommendation, applications, jailbreak, text-editor

I need to edit some local text files on my iPhone but so far, all the apps I have downloaded do not navigate the OS3 file tree for me to open, edit and save them.

I need to do this on my iPhone as I can no longer access it via `ssh` or with the iPhone cable. One of the files I want to edit is an `ssh` config file which is what is not allowing `ssh` connections.

Any suggestions of applications or other simple methods that I could use?

Comment: Load up Dropbox with your text files and download their iPhone app.

Comment: Based on your question, I added the `[jailbreak]` tag. If that's incorrect, please remove it (or let me know if I need to).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [iFile](http://iphone.heinelt.eu).

This application will let you browse the local file system.
Locate your config file, then open it using the built-in *Text Viewer*
(it also has viewers/players for other file formats such as PDF or MP3).

Despite the name the *Text Viewer* will actually let you edit and save the file.

Comment: the link is broken

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea why the link doesn't work. You will have to click the link, then use the menu to navigate to Applications > iFile

Answer (score 0):

Try this https://apps.apple.com/it/app/pretext/id1347707000 that won’t require jailbreak